# How to modify this Python function to use recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I have a simple function that breaks a number such as `54` and returns the sum of those two number (i.e. `9`). I am also studying recursion, I am wondering if the code below meets the criteria. Why? or Why Not?. If not how can I solve this simple problem using the recursion paradigm?

```
def sumnum(n):
    n = str(n)
    a = []
    for i in n:
        a.append(i) 
    sum(int(n) for n in a)
sumnum(54)
9
```

Comment: `def sumnum(n): return (sumnum(n // 10) + n % 10) if n else 0`

Comment: Recursion means a function calling itself. Does `sumnum` call itself? This would answer your question of why or why not this is recursion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code you have used is not recursion. Recursion has two main characteristics: the base case, and the recursion.

Now, lets break down you your problem:

**Base case:**

Say we have the number smaller than 10. Then we would return the number. Let's keep it as our base case.

**Recursion:**

If we had a number `...xyz` (`x`, `y` and `z` as digits), we would take the last digit, plus the last digit of the number left, until we have a number smaller than 10.

**Code:**

```
def sumnum (n):
    if n < 10:
        return n
    return n % 10 + sumnum(n // 10)
```

Comment: Note the clever use of recursion inside your explanation of recursion...

Comment: @mkrieger1 intended, indeed

Comment: I would like to know the reason for downvote, so I can improve the answer

Comment: the use of sumnum here is completely optional, why is this an optimal solution

Comment: A much more elegant base case would be `if n == 0: return 0`. Any larger number will reduce to this; specifially, `0 < n < 10` will cause `n // 10 == 0`.

Comment: @chepner I agree, but this realization will almost always come only after the `[0, 10)` base case had been established, so I figured out it be better to keep it that way